# How to pass options to dependent package installs for npm?

Tags: node.js, configuration, npm

My `node.js` project has a dependency on `node-sqlite`, but unfortunately the default `libsqlite` binary embedded there was not built with options I need.

Now I can invoke `npm install` on that package alone to get it to build correctly:

```
CFLAGS=-DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4 npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source
```

Essentially, this sets the environment variable and passes an option to the tool.

However, `npm install` by itself should just install **all** the project dependencies, including sqlite. How do I encode `package.json` or elsewhere so that `npm install` will install the sqlite dependency with the above command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [preinstall or a postinstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) script to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash

CFLAGS=-DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4 npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source;
```

Put this in `scripts/install_sqlite3_from_source.sh`, and set `scripts.preinstall` or `scripts.postinstall` in your `package.json` to it.

Comment: Hmm... doesn't this duplicate the package installing that `npm install` does? i.e. `npm install` would end up installing sqlite twice.

Comment: Oh, you'll have to remove `sqlite3` from your dependences